# MFI Accessory communicate with App via USB

Tags: ios, external-accessory, mfi

How to communicate with MFI Accessory communicate via USB?

Here's what I've got.

1. My `MFI` accessory, other company's `MFI` accessory and protocol names
   [image]
2. EADemo(An Apple official Accessory Demo)

Here's what I've done.

1. add protocol name to`Supported external accessory protocols` in EADemo-Info.plist of the EADemo.
2. Run EADemo with other accessory, send data, text of receivedBytesLabel keep changing.

When I run EADemo with my accessory, click send data, nothing changes in UI.

My colleague(a hardware developer) says I should set interface(like changing a communicate tunnel) after connecting to accessory, so that I can communicate with accessory. But I look up EASession and ExternalAccessory document, I can't find some method that would allow me to change interface. I don't know if it's my problem not setting interface, or it's a problem of the accessory?

How can my App communicate with a MFI accessory?

Comment: Do you connect your device to Lightning directly or using Lightning to USB cable?

Comment: Lighting I think. Because the lighting was integrated on the accessory.

Comment: So you have Lightning connector on your accessory and why you say about USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody has experienced this situation. I'll explain how to communicate with MFI accessory in normal way and what leads to my situation

Usually If you wanna use MFI device, you just need to do the following steps:

1. Add protocols supported by MFI to Info.plist `Supported external accessory protocols`.
2. Connect your MFI accessory to iOS device.
3. That's it. You can see data change status on screen.

`Note:` Those procedure are base on Apple official project `EADemo`, you can download from the official site.

Here's what I've been experienced:

The MFI accessory support 2 protocols, one is for connection event, the other one is data exchange(like my colleague said before, there should be 2 interface). But the manufacture didn't give the specific document. So when I connect one protocol, of course there's no data exchanging. So I connect the first protocol, and step back, connect to the second one. It works, there's data exchange status on screen.

Comment: You created two EASession objects for one accessory?

Comment: Hi @ronan.. I am in the same situation. I need to access my MFI accessory via USB in my iOS application. Currently i have used EADemo and i can fully access my MFI accessory. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Ok. but I didn't get what you're saying. As you've said that you had already get access to the accessory.